# Two problems about rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Somebody can to help me in such exercices:

> (1) A ring R such that $a^2 = a$ for all $a\in R$ is called a Boolean ring. Prove that every 
>   Boolean ring R is commutative and $a + a = 0$ for all $a \in R$.
>
> (2) Let R be a ring with more than one element such that for each nonzero $a\in R$ there is a unique $b \in R$ such that $aba = a$. Prove:
>
> > (a) R has no zero divisors.
> >
> > (b) $bab = b$.
> >
> > (c) R has an identity.
> >
> > (d) R is a division ring.

My greatest difficulty in the question 2 is to prove that R has no zero divisors.

Thanks!

Comment: Can some1 do the whole of (2) please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a+a=(a+a)^2=a^2+a^2+a^2+a^2=a+a+a+a$, so $a+a=0$.

$a+b=(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ba+b^2=a+ab+ba+b$, so $ab+ba=0$.  Using the previous fact, $ab-ba=0$ so $ab=ba$.

Comment: Thanks! I think that my wrong was to try to prove in first that is commutative.

Answer (score 2):

For part (a):
Assume that $d$ is a zero divisor, i.e., $d\neq 0$. Thus, there exists a unique $c \in R$ such that $dcd = d$, and $dc = 0$.

Since $d$ is a zero divisor, $d = dcd = (dc)d = 0\cdot d = 0$, i.e., $d=0$, which contradicts the assumption that $d$ is a zero divisor.

Therefore, R has no zero divisors.

As for part (b), notice that since $R$ has no zero divisors, left and right cancellation hold. Hence, 
$aba = a \Rightarrow b(aba)b = bab \Rightarrow bab(ab)=b(ab) \Rightarrow bab=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a$ is a zero divisor.  So there is $c\ne 0$ with $ac=0$.  Notice that $a(c+b)a=a$, contradicting uniqueness of $b$.

Comment: This proof works even if $a$ is only a left- zero divisor.

Comment: Thanks! Algebra and its tricks... ;D